# ETL process in AWS using EC2-s and EFS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hive, etl, amazon-efs

I am a data engineer with experience in designing n creating data integration and ELT processes. Below is my use case, and I need to move my process to aws and would like your opinion?
My files to be processed are in s3. I need to process those files using Hadoop. I have existing logic written in hive, just need to migrate the same to aws. Is the below approach correct/ feasible?

1. Spin up a fleet of ec2 instances, initially say 5, enable autoscaling.
2. Create an EFS, and mount it on the ec2 instances.
3. Copy file from s3 to EFS as Hadoop tables.
4. Run hive queries on top of the data in EFS and create new tables.
5. Once the process is completed, move/ export the final reports table from EFS to s3 (somehow). Not sure that whether this is possible or not, if this is not possible then this entire solution is not feasible.
   6.Terminate EFS and EC2 instances.

If the above method is correct, How does the Hadoop orchestration happen using EFS?

Thanks,
KR

Answer (score 0):

> Spin up a fleet of ec2 instances, initially say 5, enable autoscaling.

I'm not sure you need the autoscaling.
why? 
let's say you start a "big" query which takes lot's of time & cpu.

auto-scale will start more instances , but how will it start run "fraction" of the query on the new machine?

all machines need to be ready before you run the query . just keep it in mind.
Or in other words: only the machines that available *now* will handle the query.

> Copy file from s3 to EFS as Hadoop tables.

There isn't any problem with this idea.
just keep in mind , you can keep the data in EFS .

if EFS is too pricy for you , 
Please check options for provision EBS-magnetic with Raid 0 .
You will gain great speeds at minimal costs.

The rest is okay, and this is one of the ways to do "on demand" interactive analytics.

Please take a look into [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/).

It's a service which allows you to run queries on s3 objects .

You can use Json and even Parquet (which is much more efficient !)

This service may be enough for your need .

Good luck !

Comment: Currently we are using EC2+EBS solution, and its R0. Say we have 10 nodes (static count for entire length of the process) 2-dataNodes n rest computeNodes.
For the time bieng lets forget autoscaling.
Still, is it possible to orchestrate these EC2s to simulate a hadoop cluster which referrs EFS as the source? I am not used to EFS, thats why.


~KR

Comment: Yes , is much more simpler then you think .  Take a look here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html

Comment: You can connect from multiple machines to the same NFS . Now you can choose between IO modes ... so let’s say you need EFS to be really fast you can switch to Provision mode , later switch back ...

Comment: The IO mode is part of the EFS configuration ... and your use case is exactly fit this way ..